# How can one transform polar functions along rectangular coordinates?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Suppose one has a function $r = g(\theta).$ What I would like to do is control how it shifts horizontally and vertically as I would in a rectangular function $ y =f(x+a)+b.$ Is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Can you please add some context and elaborate more

Comment: Sorry, I assumed these were conventional high school topics covered in most high schools in the world. If you have a rectangular function, you can translate it horizontally with $f(x+a)$ by $a$ units, or vertically with $f(x)+b$ by $b$ units. All I'm looking to do is control that same left/right, up/down movement but in polar coordinates. If you have a polar function $r = g(\theta),$ taking $g(\theta) + b$ obviously doesn't translate it up or down, it expands the radius. But, I want to be able to control that up/down, left-right behavior, but in polar coordinates.

Comment: You can convert to cartesian by using $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$

Comment: But the topic is not asking to convert to Cartesian.

Comment: Than you have $y=f(r\sin{\theta}) + b$

Comment: But now you no longer have $r$ in terms of $\theta.$

Comment: There’s definitely no easy general way to do this as those are inherently Cartesian operations.

Comment: Well, I don't know of a proof that there is no easy way to do it. I would imagine there is at least $\textit{some}$ way to do it. They are not inherently Cartesian at all, if they were then polar coordinates couldn't be a coordinate system in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ It simply requires a more complicated formula. Instead of moving along constants one must in some way move along trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a nice formula, but one can compute the new $r,\,\theta$ using the laws of cosine and sine.

In the case of the shift of a polar point $A=(r_1,\theta_1)$ to the right by an amount $h$ to the point $A'=(r_2,\theta_2)$ we have by the law of cosines that

$$ r_2^2=r_1^2+h^2-2r_1h\cos(\pi-\theta_1) $$

and by the law of sines that

$$ \sin(\theta_2)=\frac{r_1\sin(\pi-\theta_1)}{r_2} $$

One could analyze left, up and down shifts in a similar fashion.

[image: right shift of polar point]

Comment: The formula doesn't necessarily need to be nice, but I also don't see how this answers the question as a function of $r$ in terms of $\theta.$

Comment: I don't see how that could be done in general.

Comment: Right, that's why this post does not successfully answer the question.